# Excel trying to display most recent refresh time and date to a database query connection

Tags: excel, vba

As the title suggests I'm just trying to find out how I can display the date and time of a connection refresh.  I haven't been able to find a direct answer to this question anywhere.  Please let me know, and I can clarify more as needed. Also, I have Excel 2013.

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more specific. What do you mean by connection refresh? What database are you querying? Is it querying via a macro, or is it a linked data source (from the Data tab in Excel)? How do you want to output the date/time of the refresh? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Googling `excel query connections last update timestamp` yielded this result, which should help you `https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/time-stamp-when-query-is-refreshed/0987771f-72a8-4afb-9889-ea9891e03624`

Comment: @JoshEller the connection is a linked data source.  a server based SQL connection.  It's set to refresh every 5 minutes.  I would like to just output to a cell for now.  And I have tried

Comment: @JoshEller 
    `Sub Macro1()
          ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll With Range("A1") .Value = Now() 
         .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" 
     End With 
     End Sub –`